# How to fix Cyrillic characters while web-scraping with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, character-encoding, cyrillic

I'm scraping a Cyrillic website with python using BeautifulSoup, but I'm having some trouble, every word is showing like this:

> Ð¡Ð¸Ð»ÑÐ°Ð½Ð¾Ð²ÑÐºÐ° ÐÐ°Ð²ÐºÐ¾Ð²Ð° Ð²Ð¾ ÐÐ°Ð·Ð¸

I also tried some other Cyrillic websites, but they are working good.

My code is this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

print(soup.prettify())
```

How should I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`requests` fails to detect it as `utf-8`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://time.mk/')  # don't convert to text just yet

# print(source.encoding)
# prints out ISO-8859-1

source.encoding = 'utf-8'  # override encoding manually

soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, 'lxml')  # this will now decode utf-8 correctly
```

Comment: The site doesn't serve a content-type header so `requests` falls back to ISO-8859-1/latin-1.  However there is a meta tag in the html that defines the charset, so another approach might be to pass `source.content` to `BeautifulSoup` and let `BeautifulSoup` handle the decoding.

Comment: when I add this line " source.encoding = 'utf-8' " I don't have any errors but the output is blank !? Did you get any result with this?

Comment: @scpbook setting a variable doesn't print anything. Just like `foo = 42` doesn't print anything unless you `print(foo)`. You can add a `print(source.encoding)` on the following line to test it, or simply see if it fixed your problem. It has for me, at least.

Comment: @PatrykBratkowski of course im printing it, my code:
`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://time.mk/')

source.encoding = 'utf-8'

soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, 'lxml')

print(soup)`

It shows that i have 2740 lines of text, but when I open it its empty.

Comment: @scpbook I think you should make a new post, if you are having a different problem now, as SO isn't really suited to discuss it in comments. [The code I posted definitely works](https://i.imgur.com/YwyB11L.png).

Comment: It's not able to preserve chars like а̄ - they become 